# HTML5 input pattern match validation for numer between 0 and 22

Tags: regex, html, validation

How can I use pattern validation for input, if I want numbers from 0 to 22? I know that I can use:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="22" />
```

but I have to use `type="text"`i was trying with that regexp: `/^(0?[1-9]|2[012])$/`but it's not what I expected.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 0 to 22, you need to use

```
pattern="[10]?[0-9]|2[012]"
```

Note that you do not need to use `^` and `$`, since `pattern` attribute anchors the regex by default wrapping it with `^(?:` (at the start) and `)$` (at the end).

**How does it work**: `[10]?[0-9]` matches an optional `1` or `0` and any digit after it (that is, `0`/`00` till `19`), or (`|`) `2[012]` matches `2` and then either `0`, `1` or `2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tlzVYE/1)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="form1"> 
 <input pattern="[10]?[0-9]|2[012]" title=""/>
 <input type="Submit"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for your understanding and help. It works

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but you did not take into account numbers starting with `1`:

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-2])$/
```

Comment: Actually, `0` or `00` value was not accounted for either in the OP regex.